# Web2py: Using a bootstrap modal for insert, update and delete

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, load, web2py

I would like to use a bootstrap modal to create new and update existing records.
It works for new records but I cannot get it to work for updating existing ones and also not to delete.

What am I doing wrong in the post.load views and in the comments.py.get_comment code?

I would appreciate any help or guidance.

**models/tables.py**

```
db.define_table('comment_post',
    Field('title','string',label='Comment title', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('body','text',label='Your comment', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    auth.signature)
```

**controllers/default.py**

```
def index():
    return dict()
```

**views/default/index.html**

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

Comments
{{=LOAD('comments','post.load',ajax=True)}}
```

**controllers/comments.py**

```
@auth.requires_login()
def post():
    form = SQLFORM(db.comment_post, formstyle='bootstrap3_stacked').process()

    if form.accepted:
        response.flash = 'You have successfully submitted the form'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'Please check your form for errors'
    else:
        response.flash = 'Please complete the form'

    comments = db(db.comment_post).select(orderby=~db.comment_post.id, limitby=(0, 3))
    return dict(form=form, comments=comments)

@auth.requires_login()
def get_comment():
    r = db.auth_user(request.vars.id) or redirect(URL('post'))
    form = SQLFORM(db.comment_post, r).process()
    return form.xml

@auth.requires_login()
def delete_comment():
    return db(db.comment_post.id == request.vars.id).delete()
```

**views/comments/post.load**

```
{{for post in comments:}}
    <div class="post">{{=post.title}}: on <small>{{=post.created_on}}</small> {{=post.created_by.first_name}}
        <small>said:</small> "<span class="post_body">{{=post.body}}</span>"
        {{=A('Edit', callback=URL('welcome', 'comments', 'get_comment', vars={'id': post.id}), target="form_load")}}
        {{=A('Delete', callback=URL('welcome', 'comments', 'delete_comment', vars={'id': post.id}))}}
    </div>
{{pass}}

<hr>

<!-- Button trigger modal: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="form_load" class="modal-body">
        {{=form}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```